# Identifying The Control Panel Applets GUID in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, applet, guid, controlpanel

I am looking for a way to identify the GUIDs for some applets in my Windows 10 Pro Control Panel.

[image: Windows 10 Pro Control Panel]

One set of the applets is the Control Panel (Category View), while the others are visible in the Icons Mode. They are third party programs - Mail (which comes from Microsoft Outlook 2010) and the Flash Player (32-bit).

[image: third party programs]

Apologies if I've come to the wrong site, but I do not know where else to go for assistance/advice. Other forums cannot help me.

Regards,
Andrew